# Passing static param to ActionLink in Controller context (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, parameter-passing

Is it possible to add some route that always add some param in url? 
For example when I write something link this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Site", "Index", "Admin")
```

It routes to admin/index?key=some_auth_key. For example I save this param in some static class/variable.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Site", "Index", "Admin", new { key = yourValue }, null)` but if its static, why not just get the value in the method you redirecting to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke 
it's something like auth key. When once you successfully entered, later all your links starting to have this param

Comment: Its not clear what or why you wanting to do this. (and a use can just enter `/Admin/Index` in the address bar which means the `key` would not be passed)

Comment: it this case I catch the request, check url and if no key, then send him unauth page.

Comment: Sorry, but its not making sense. It sounds like you wanting authorization, which you do with the `[Authorize]` attribute (and where a user is not authorized, they are automatically redirected to a login page)

Comment: I create custom auth attribute, now it checks only url param for key param. Look, you open browser, enter admin/key=secure_key and enter some page. In page there are also another links. For example admin/product/edit. But you also need this secure_key to go admin/product/edit/1/key=secure_key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164055/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-grigor-aleksanyan).

Answer (score 0):

**4th parameter of Html.ActionLink can have any number of properties:**

```
Html.ActionLink("Check this", "Edit", "test", 
                 new { id = id, data=name }, new { style = "display:block" })
```

These properties are inserted into URL based on routing, but if the property name cannot be matched into any route it is added as URL GET parameter.

So if you have standard route **{controller}/{action}/{id}**, you will get the URL:

```
test/Edit/[id]?data=[name]
```